# Stretched texture - how to fix?

Tags: texturing, uv

I tried to texture a ravine.
First I selected a shape for it and scaled it down in Z. I know it's now streched and I scaled (CTRL + A)  it.
To texture the wall down, my first try was to create a Vertex Group for the wall and create a own material with Assign. This didn't look correct and I decided to paint the texture with the UV Editing, but as you can see in my screenshot, it looks so stretched and I have no idea what's wrong.
Has anyone an idea?

[image]

Comment: Your UV's are messed up, this happens when your UV's are stretched and/or squished. You need to have proper UV if you want to texture paint.

Comment: @mqbakamqbaka how can I fix it?